# Sending Form with Table Data together with multiple Inputs via Submit button

Tags: php, html, forms, button

Let's consider following html:

```
<form action="Action.php" method="POST">
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12" style="text-align: left">
         <table>
            <tbody>
               <td><label><input type="text" name="foldersTable['folderName'][]" value="foldername"></label></td>
            </tbody>
         </table>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12" style="text-align: left">
         <div style="display: inline-block;">
            <img src="deleteSelected.jpg">
            <button type="submit" id="1">
               <input type="hidden" name="action" value="Files::deleteSelected">
               Delete Selected
            </button>
         </div>
         <div style="display: inline-block;">
            <img src="zip.jpg">
            <button type="submit" id="2">
               <input type="hidden" name="action" value="Zip::zipSelectedFolders">
               Zip Selected
            </button>
         </div>

         <div style="display: inline-block;">
            <img src="rename.jpg">
            <button type="submit" id="3">
               <input type="hidden" name="action" value="Files::renameFolders">
               Rename Selected
            </button>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</form>
```

What I want is to send all data in table (which works) together with information about the inside of the hidden input (info which action should occure on click in value, ie "Files::deleteSelected").
Unfortunatelly If I click on button ID 1, I would expect to see "Files::deleteSelected". But I get always the last hidden input, which means "Files::renameFolders":
[XdebugPost screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ay0RA.png)

How can I adjust that code in order to always get hidden input of the button I clicked on?

Or maybe better question - I can see, this implementation is not good one. How else can I send all data in table together with custom data in the button I clicked on?

I can see some javascript answers suggested, however I would much prefer not using any "magic". I think there should be some way how to do that.

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: having a hidden input inside a button is a bit weird. Just give the button itself a name and a value. Make sure the names are unique. Then in the PHP you can detect which one was used.

Comment: Thanks, you are correct :) info is there... erasing hidden inputs solved that, before I had info from all of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can do:

```
<button type="submit" id="1" name="action"  value="Files::deleteSelected">Delete Selected</button>
```

instead of:

```
<button type="submit" id="1">
           <input type="hidden" name="action" value="Files::deleteSelected">
           Delete Selected
        </button>
```

So when you click the button you get the data you need.

Another option is to replace your buttons and those hidden inputs by one submit button and a radio button choice between Files::deleteSelected, Zip::zipSelectedFolders, Files::renameFolders.

This way you can also set a default option to make sure that you are always recieving that data.

You may also consider using JavaScript.